# Have a any control library which provide all asp.net control in HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html, controls

In the market there is many solution of HTML5 browser compatibility so I want to use HTML5 in asp.net. I want to know best control library of that...

Answer (score 1):

Please check out http://html5asp.sourceforge.net  It's open source, so you can add anything you don't find or suggest enhancements.